# How to connect reducers logic

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

```
const authReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(startLogin, (state) => ({...state, isLogging: true})),
  on(loginSuccessful, (state) => ({...state /*do sth other */})),
  on(loginSuccessful, loginFailed, (state) => ({...state, isLogging: false}))
);
```

In example above I have shared logic between multiple actions (`isLogging` property).
But only one of these reducers will be fired when loginSuccesfull action was dispatched.

It is possible to connect shared logic instead of writing:

```
const authReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(startLogin, (state) => ({...state, isLogging: true})),
  on(loginSuccessful, (state) => ({...state, isLogging: false /*do sth other */})),
  on(loginFailed, (state) => ({...state, isLogging: false}))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible (for now), only the last registered action of the same action's type receives the update.

```
const authReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(startLogin, (state) => ({...state, isLogging: true})),
  on(loginSuccessful, (state) => ({...state /*do sth other */})),
  on(loginSuccessful, loginFailed, (state) => ({...state, isLogging: false})) // only this one will be triggered for loginSuccessful
);
```

We just merged a [PR](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/2103) to make your use case possible, this will probably get "out" with the next release.

Comment: Great job! Thank you @Tim